# How to use is_single and get_post_type within a plugin?

Tags: plugins

I am trying to use the above two functions within a plugin I am trying to build and obviously they don't work because plugins are loaded before a page is ready and before a post is loaded to know what post type it is.

Which that said, how can I work around that?  I am just trying to do something simple like so:

```
if ( is_single() && get_post_type() == 'boxy' ) {
$setting = 200;
}
```

But this statement never becomes true per above reasons.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 10):

You need to hook into an appropriate place within the WordPress load sequence.

For example,

```
add_action('init', 'my_function'); //is too early and won't work!
```

Where as,

```
add_action('wp', 'my_function'); //will work!
```

And so too will,

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'my_function'); //this works too!
```

In fact `template_redirect` fires just before rendering the page/post to the viewer so its an appropriate place to hook into to perform your action.

Take the following example, if it were placed within your plugin file, will successfully pass the `is_single` conditional check, then proceed to add a filter which replaces `the_content` with a completely custom result, in this case a simple string which outputs `new content` will be displayed in place of what is held in the database.

```
function plugin_function(){
    
    if(is_single()) {
    
        add_filter('the_content', 'filter_content');
        
        function filter_content(){
            echo 'new content';
        }
        
    }
    
}

add_action('template_redirect', 'plugin_function');
```

As an example, try changing the last line above to read,

```
add_action('init', 'plugin_function');
```

Using the `init` hook is to early, instead of seeing our filtered content as in the function above, you'll notice the regular post content from the database is shown instead.

Hope this helps.

#### UPDATE

Since you mentioned in your comments you're using a CLASS, are you using a constructor for your `add_action/add_filter`?

**Example:**

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', array( 'YourClassNmae', 'init' ) );

class YourClassNmae {

    public static function init() {
        $class = __CLASS__;
        new $class;
    }

    public function __construct() {
         //your actions/filters are to be added here... 
         add_filter('the_content', array( $this, 'filter_content') );
    }

         public function filter_content(){
             echo 'new content';
         }
     
}
```

**Codex Reference:** [Using add_action with a class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action#Using_add_action_with_a_class)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I think I have tried template_redirect but it didn't work.  Maybe I am not applying it in the right place?  I am writing this plugin in an object style with a class and I am using this to instantiate my classes add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'bbe_run_plugin' ); and I have tried changing that to 'template_redirect' and didn't seem to work.  Thanks for the help

Comment: @Rick Can you please post your full code, if its excessively large you can trim it down to relevant context, or use pastebin. Also while you're at it, try `is_singular('boxy')` instead of `get_post_type` which by the way means you can drop the `is_single` because `is_singular` will be running that check for you.

Comment: @Rick See above for an example CLASS structure in your plugin that should work for you.

Comment: thanks again for the patience and reply. Here is a sample code of how I currently have it and of course I trimmed out most of it and left only necessary items. Please see -> http://pastebin.com/JYXvxa3u

Comment: might be nice to edit that pastebin into your original post

Comment: I would not use template_redirect, because it is often used for, well, template redirects! Processing typically ends after that. As such, a theme or another plugin might end processing before your plugin gets a chance to run its bit. (have seen this in the wild)

Comment: @webaware Can you provide some context/example? Hooking onto `template_redirect` allows your processing to occur within the context of this hook before the layout is rendered to screen. If a theme or another plugin ends processing before this hook is being fired, what then is being rendered to screen? I would say nothing is. If that is the context in which you are wanting to know if something `is_single` or so on, then `template_redirect` is fine to use, else you can use another hook up the chain as suggested. I'd still like to see some more context provided to your comment though? Cheers mate

Comment: [wp-e-commerce vs NextGEN Gallery](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-nextgen-gallery-template_redirect-should-be-wp_print_scriptswp_print_styles) (recently fixed in NextGEN Gallery by using enqueue scripts hook instead). wp-e-commerce uses template_redirect to redirect the template (gosh!) and it exits just after `include($template);`

Comment: @webaware In that example, NextGEN are using the wrong hook for the intended purpose of script injection. Agreed. Although, it is a bit presumptuous on behalf of WP-eCommerce that no one else outside their plugin would want to use `template_redirect` nor be allowed to for that matter! That's a akin to saying, *"if WP-eCommerce is installed no one else dare use `template_redirect` or else!"* - what if that's the most appropriate context? It could be solved with **priority** but even so I still think thats more or less a poor design decision on WP-eComm's behalf. What is your suggested solution?

Comment: But the whole purpose of template_redirect is to ... redirect the template. Every action/filter after that depends on the template anyway (e.g. the template should call wp_head() and wp_footer(), and content hooks/filters depend on The Loop stuff). The template_redirect hook doesn't give you any other way to redirect to another template. If anything, using template_redirect for side effects and expecting nobody to use it for its intended purpose, then getting upset about it, is a "bit presumptuous" :)

Comment: @webaware We both know what the purpose of `template_redirect` is, yay, but your last sentence is... confusing. Who's getting upset? You presuming I'm upset? Are you upset? Don't get upset bro. What if Tom, Dick and Harry all want to use `template_redirect` for its "intended purpose" but each of which decide to `exit` after hooking onto this action? Then what? We going to have a hook-off? This is what I am talking about. Also I asked for your suggested solution, because your example thus far shows one plugin using the hook in the wrong context. For the sake of educating others, what say you?

Comment: No, I'm not upset, I misread your emphasis. If every Tom, Dick and Harry wanted to use template_redirect for its intended purpose, they'd only be redirecting to their templates when it's appropriate. Which would undermine anyone relying on template_redirect as a side-effect. So what's wrong with tying your action to something that doesn't run the risk of skipping past other hooks, like wp, wp_head etc.? Anyway, SO is warning me to move this to chat, and I'd rather get a small glass with some ice now :) (7pm Friday night here) so... cheers!

Comment: @webaware 7pm Friday night here too... so I hope that glass has something else to go with that ice.

Comment: Yes, Bourbon :)